# Track active logging to log files

Tags: ubuntu, logs, syslog

Is there a way to track which service/file is actively logging to a log file?  In this case taking info from the syslog file and creating a file called filtered.log.   I'm not seeing a process for this when doing a ps aux but am seeing almost constant logging to this file.  Using Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you tracking? You seem to know that you want to read a syslog file and write to a filtered.log, so -- what do you want to track, and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the command you are looking for is `lsof`. From the `lsof` manual:

> lsof - list open files

Under the examples section therein:

> To find the process that has /u/abe/foo open, use:
>
> ```
>            lsof /u/abe/foo
> ```

I have an nginx webserver logging to `/var/log/nginx/access.log` so I did a test:

```
$ sudo lsof /var/log/nginx/access.log
[sudo] password for <username>:
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
nginx   1667 root    5w   REG  254,2  7981659 1572890 /var/log/nginx/access.log
nginx   6283 http    5w   REG  254,2  7981659 1572890 /var/log/nginx/access.log
nginx   6284 http    5w   REG  254,2  7981659 1572890 /var/log/nginx/access.log
nginx   6285 http    5w   REG  254,2  7981659 1572890 /var/log/nginx/access.log
nginx   6286 http    5w   REG  254,2  7981659 1572890 /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

Which seems to be what you are after.

Comment: Not all applications write directly to log files, the culprit of the question can be an app sending messages to the syslog daemon. +1 nonetheless

Comment: Thanks, good point. But then wouldn't `lsof` still show that the syslog daemon is writing to the file? It's not a topic I've delved into much before.

Comment: For sure, but then you would have to use other method to track the actual app sending the messages. T he actual question lacks a sample of the lines in question

Comment: Yeah, makes sense

Comment: Thanks, I found what I was looking for with this.